# android studio - how to add spinner to popupwindow in service

Tags: java, android-studio, android-spinner

i've some kind of problems here !! i've code that shows a popupwindow from my service and inside this popupwindow there is a spinner and when i click the spinner the errors start to show off on me :'(
here is the code used :

```
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null, false), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
            final Spinner spn_ = (Spinner)pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
            final String[] options_alma_ = {"Hello","HI"};
            final ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter_ = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AlMA_Service.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, options_alma_);
            final Button btn = (Button)pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.button10);
            btn.setText("Choose Hello");
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("Clicked", "Here Before Dismiss !!");
                    pw.dismiss();
                }
            });
            spn_.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter_);
            spn_.setSelection(stringArrayAdapter_.getPosition(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName()));
            spn_.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    try {
                        btn.setText("Choose " + stringArrayAdapter_.getItem(position));
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        btn.setText("Choose Hello" );
                        }
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
            pw.showAsDropDown(mView);
```

any help ??

Comment: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@fd99cea is not valid; is your activity running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is you cannot reliably pass the currently active activity to the popup window
 There will be some way of passing activity unreliably but I do not recommend it

You can try this instead of popupmenu

```
windowManager2 = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupmenu, null); 
params=new WindowManager.LayoutParams( WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
 params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER;
 params.x=0; 
params.y=0; 
windowManager2.addView(view, params);
```

Comment: thanks mate , but this is service with button on screen overlay .
it's added by windowmanager and my code above is just inside button.onclicklistener

Comment: thanks mate (y) i've tested this and it worked fine !! thanks a lot ^^